# Global Azure CDN for China Azure

Tags: azure

How Global Azure CDN different is from China Azure CDN ? Do I need to make any changes in Azure CDN if i want to use the same Azure CDN in China Azure ?

Please clear my doubt.

Thanks,
Vishwajeet.

Answer (score 0):

Azure China is sepeate infrastructure managed from a separate portal

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/regions/

### Azure in China is available through a unique partnership between Microsoft and 21Vianet, one of the country’s largest Internet providers.

https://www.azure.cn/

Answer (score 0):

> How Global Azure CDN different is from China Azure CDN ?

Global Azure CDN works for global, for example, we can select  to different country.

But China Azure CDN **only** can work in China (China East and China North).

More information about China Azure CDN, please refer to this [link](https://www.azure.cn/home/features/cdn/).

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.